# How get huge data from sql server using ado.net?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm getting error  while fetching the data

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Error getting line is   `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);`

**(2826000) records count in my table.**

here is the code i'm using.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var DicTableNameAndValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM  " + table;
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(dataQuery, connection))
    {
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList().Select(c => c.ItemArray);
        DicTableNameAndValues.Add(table, result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of this method doesn't say it throws `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: How about getting only the required number of records from the database instead of bringing all the records on the client side and then taking only a few out of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a certain number of records as required by your application instead of all the records. You can create a stored procedure something to the effect of the following.

```
--Create a stored procedure with following parameters
DECLARE @skip int, @pagesize int

--Added testing values
SELECT @skip = 4, @pagesize = 3

--Give @tbl with your table name. 
/*If you already have an identity key then probably row_number function might not 
be required. But if the records are getting deleted as well then row_number is a
better option*/
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY Your_Col) AS ROWNUM, * FROM @tbl) as tbl
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN (@skip * @pagesize) + 1 and (@skip + 1) * (@pagesize)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Samar Thanks.. it is working but some tables i have composite keys as primary key. so there i'm getting jumbled data (like not in proper order ).

Comment: Are you using ROW_NUMBER function? If yes then you can give multiple column names inside order by as follows. SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY Your_Col1, Your_Col2) AS ROWNUM,...